# Minimum number of points chosen from an $N$ by $N$ grid to guarantee a rectangle?

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-geometry

What is the **maximum** number of points that can be chosen from an $N$ by $N$ grid such that no $4$ of the chosen points form a rectangle with sides parallel to the axes of the grid?

Equivalently, what is the minimum number of points chosen from an $N$ by $N$ grid to guarantee a rectangle?

What if we remove also rule out rectangles with sides not parallel to the axes of the grid?

Comment: Searching for papers, this problem seems related to the [Zarankiewicz problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zarankiewicz_problem).  [This paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0097316575900072) by Roman relates the problem to the one given here and generalizes it, giving a great deal of detail, even citing a result by Reiman that implies that certainly one cannot place $\frac{n}{2}+n^{3/2}+1$ without causing a rectangle to occur.  Whether this bound is tight, I have not yet read enough to verify.

Comment: I posted an answer claiming that $3n-3$ is the max # of points guaranteed to have no rectangle; since this is stronger than the bound you mention, I am almost certainly wrong...

Comment: I solved the equivalent problem for right triangles with sides parallel to the axes, and the answer is 2N-2. For parallelograms, its 2N-1. For isosceles trapezoids its at most 5/2N-1. These are all O(n) so I would be somewhat surprised if the answer for rectangles wasn't O(n).

Comment: Edit: there was an obvious flaw in my answer (an arithmetic mistake!!!!!!).

Comment: I apologize for flooding with comments, but that is because I am unable to contribute a proper answer.  Still, it is worth mentioning, the article I linked to from sciencedirect has on what is labeled as page 194, table $1^a$, a table of some known values of $M_{2,2}(m,n)$.  In particular, it implies that for an $8\times 8$ grid, one can place $24$ points without a rectangle, unfortunately more than $3\cdot 8-3=21$, implying the guess of $3n-3$ is incorrect.  Results of the table from *R. K. GUY, A problem of 
Zarankiewicz, in “Theory of Graphs,” Academic Press, New York, 1968.*

Comment: What I've been reading implies that the bound given is tight and that the limit does approach $n^{3/2}$.  Chasing the citations, it appears to trace back to a paper from 1954 by Kovari, Sos, and Turan (*I have sadly not yet found a link to the original paper*).  [Some more recent results](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0097316596900679) using more modern techniques continue to verify this.

Comment: @JMoravitz: This is [OEIS sequence A072567](https://oeis.org/A072567). Strangely, the values $M_{2,2}(14,14)=56$ and $M_{2,2}(15,15)=60$ in the table that you linked to haven't been taken into account there; the entry ends at $n=13$. These values are surprisingly low, with two increments of $4$ where the increments before had been $5,5,5,6,7$. I wonder whether the OEIS editor had reason to doubt them. I can't find the contribution from R. K. Guy that they're quoted from. By the way, the first value greater than $3n-3$ is $16$ for $n=6$. The entry also gives the growth rate as $n^{3/2}$.

Comment: I gave an approximate answer to a duplicate question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2272443/rectangle-with-lattice-points